# React app not running useEffect when tab is not in focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react app receiving updates to all subscribed clients via socket,

When a new socket message comes in, I’m firing a dispatch action

```
io.on(EVENT, ({ someData }) => { 
  console.log(newDate());
  dispatch(handleEventUpdate(someData)); 
});
```

This action only gets fired when the tab gets in focus.
The date log also matching the exact time the tab comes in focus, any ideas how to make this execute even when the tab is not in focus?

Since JS doesn’t run when tab is not in focus which I think is the issue, I’m Currently trying to use a service worker approach to handle this but I’m not sure where to start from.

Context

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import ChildComp from './ChildComp';


import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import ChildComp from './ChildComp';
const ParentComp = () => {
const { data } = useSelector(
        (state) => state,
    );
  return <ChildComp data={data} />;
};
export default ParentComp;


import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
const ChildComp = ({ data }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('state changed');
        console.log(data);
        return () => {
            console.log('component cleanup');
        };
    },  [data]);
    return <p> {data} </p>;
};
export default ChildComp;


The parent gets the state data and passes to the child component. The update doesn't reflect if the tab isn't in focus until you go back to the tab.
```

Comment: Since JS doesn’t run  ... please be more specific !

Comment: Updated the above to show the components in question

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code simply by adding a dependency. The issue here is that you are not providing enough code...

```
io.on(EVENT, ({ someData }) => { 
  console.log(newDate());
  dispatch(handleEventUpdate(someData)); 
}, [/*a value of foucus and not foucus that changes ! that will rerender the component*/]);
```